# Why does my Web API return only JSON?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5

I just applied Update 2 RTM to Visual Studio 2013 and started a new Web API project. I have a basic service returning some people objects.

I'm trying to use content negotiation to return JSON or XML depending on the Accept header. Regardless of the Accept header, I get JSON. How do I troubleshoot this and return XML or JSON depending on the header?

Here is the Header from Fiddler: `Accept: application/xml`

Here is the body of my Get() method:

```
var patient = this.patientRepository.GetPatients().Where(p => p.Identifier == id).FirstOrDefault();

IContentNegotiator negotiator = this.Configuration.Services.GetContentNegotiator();

ContentNegotiationResult result = negotiator.Negotiate(typeof(Patient), this.Request, this.Configuration.Formatters);

if (result == null)
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable);
    throw new HttpResponseException(response);
}

return new HttpResponseMessage()
{
    Content = new ObjectContent<Patient>(patient, result.Formatter, result.MediaType.MediaType)
};
```

Thanks!

Update - Here is the WebApiConfig.cs. I added the line adding the XmlMediaTypeFormatter. By default, it's not included. Either way, the issue is not resolved.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new XmlMediaTypeFormatter());


    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: During content negotiation each formatter is asked whether it can `write` a type. Its possible that the xml formatter might have said that it cannot write a particular type whereas json formatter might have said yes. This is the default behavior. If you like to change this, you can replace the default contnent negotiator by doing something like `config.Services.Replace(typeof(IContentNegotiator), new DefaultContentNegotiator(excludeMatchOnTypeOnly: true))` in which case if a formatter cannot write, then a 406 response is sent back. BTW, why are you running con-neg yourself?

Comment: I added the conneg because OOTB it wasn't working - I was not getting any XML data back. My understanding of Web API content negotiation is to use the Accept header and everything needed to get XML back is built into the framework.

Comment: I am getting the aforementioned 406 response. Now, how do I fix it? Do I need to implement a custom ContentNegotiator or is there already one built in and I just need to use it?

Comment: No, do not write a custom conneg...the problem here is that XML formatter might be unable to write your type, so you need to figure why it is so...Xml formatter by default uses DataContractSerializer to serialize a type, so check if your type is compatible with it..

Comment: DOH! I Forgot to add `[DataMember]` attributes to my business object... Everything is working as expected after adding the `[DataContract]` attribute to the class and the `[DataMember]` attribute to the properties.